# Add value of txtfields to another txtfield

Tags: php, javascript, html, textfield, calculator

I need to know how to add values from about 10 textfields,add the sums onChange, and have it give me the sum into another textfield within a form.

So when i hit submit the textfield "total" will be sent with the form
example:

```
<form>
<input name="qty" type="text"  size="8" />
<input name="qty2" type="text"  size="8" />
<input name="qty3" type="text"  size="8" />
<input name="qty4" type="text"  size="8" />
<input name="qty5" type="text"  size="8" />
<input name="qty6" type="text"  size="8" />
<br />
<br />
<input name="total" type="text"  size="8" id="total" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<form id="form">
<input onkeypress="send()" onchange="send()" name="qty" type="text"  size="8" />
<input onkeypress="send()" onchange="send()" name="qty2" type="text"  size="8" />
<input onkeypress="send()" onchange="send()" name="qty3" type="text"  size="8" />
<input onkeypress="send()" onchange="send()" name="qty4" type="text"  size="8" />
<input onkeypress="send()" onchange="send()" name="qty5" type="text"  size="8" />
<input onkeypress="send()" onchange="send()" name="qty6" type="text"  size="8" />
<br />
<br />
<input name="total" type="text"  size="8" id="total"  />
</form>
<script>
function send(){
    var sum=0;
    var input = document.getElementById('form').getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (i=0;i<input.length-1;i++){
        if((input[i].name!='total')&&(!isNaN(parseInt(input[i].value)))){
            sum+=parseInt(input[i].value);
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('total').value=sum;
}
</script>
```

Comment: i need it to add the values on change, so i should see the numbers change as i type them in the fields while the sum changes in the "total" txfield

Comment: post your form, I can't even image how is your form...or adapt it yourself

Comment: @AlessandroGabrielli Apologies if the meme offended you Alessandro! I was just warning Fabien before his answer received more downvotes (answering a JavaScript question that doesn't mention jQuery with a jQuery solution will bring downvotes sadly) :)

Comment: @Zenith No, I don't feel offended. I agree that giving not enough info it's not a good reply but as the rules say: "any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful". As it's an error to upvote too much low info, it's the same an error to downvote with no reason, this last one, probably more, this both for questions and answer.. I just watched the the other face of the medal in that image.

Comment: @AlessandroGabrielli It's true, but I have seen answers like that downvoted 5/6 times! The original poster didn't mention jQuery and probably isn't using it for his project, so a jQuery solution wouldn't help them, but I see your point (I didn't downvote him, just warned him why others would).

Comment: @Zenith Yes I know, I got downvoted for less. You show a good behaviour by warn him. Surely you are more experienced then me here,but I think that the way the question was posted, gave enough freedom in the replies. See you around